# Spliting string based on length from end in PHP

Tags: php, string, split

I want to split a string from behind. Like:

```
$mystring = "this is my string";
$mysecondstring = "thisismystring";
```

I want to split the last 6 characters from the above strings, here it is "string". How can I do this in PHP?
Using **str_split**, I can split from the front side, but I need from the end.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`substr()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.substr.php)

**edit**

```
$snippet = substr($mystring, 0, -6);
```

Comment: i want to remove "string", do not want to show last 6 characters.

Comment: Updated to reflect your clarification

Answer (score 1):

Was looking for something like it too, (almost 10 years later ..)
Here it's what i've made :

```
function str_split_end($string, $length) {
    $string = strrev($string);
    $array = str_split($string, $length);
    $array = array_reverse($array);
    for($i = 0; $i < sizeof($array); $i++) {
        $array[$i] = strrev($array[$i]);
    }
    return $array;
}
```

In your case, the function will return with **$mystring** :

```
array (
    0 => 'this ',
    1 => 'is my ',
    2 => 'string',
)
```

And with **$mysecondstring** :

```
array (
    0 => 'th',
    1 => 'isismy',
    2 => 'string',
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `str_split()` will Convert a string to an array

But can get the same result output you want in an array form

```
// The first parameter would the string you want to split.
// then the second parameter would be in what length you want the string to be splitted.

str_split(parameter1,parameter2)
```

Example.

```
$mystring = " this is my string ";

// we put length of string to be splitted by 6 because its the string length of "string"
$myString = str_split($myString,6);
```

It will generate a result of :

```
Output:
Array
(
    [0] => " this " 
    [1] => "is my "
    [2] => "string"

// then you can 
echo $string[2] 
//for the value of "string" being splitted.
```

)

*note: if your using `str_split()` to get a value you want you must have a good division length for it. That why i add extra spaces in the value of `$mystring` to only produce an output array of `"string"` as value*